# Specific letters on keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard

I've got an HP 6830S laptop, and the keys <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>Q</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> all aren't working.  They also don't work if I use an external keyboard.  I already reinstalled all my drivers with no effect.

Comment: Do the keys work it the BIOS, in Safe Mode and/or in another OS (boot a Linux LiveCD)?

Comment: Only thing I can imagine is that something on your system is redirecting those keys' behaviour. A bit like how you can install a third-party screenshot app and it'll block the PrintScreen key's default behaviour. Yes, odd that it would include letter keys, but I can hardly imagine another cause. Now, as to what exactly this "something" is, you're going to have to investigate. I second trying another OS. If you determine the issue is software, maybe just remaking an user account will fix it all. If I were you, I'd try that and check startup programs and malware before giving up and formating.

Comment: Thank you for response , in BIOS the same problem , but occasionally it works , is it maby some conflict in drivers ?

Comment: Does an external keyboard work if you disconnect the internal one? In which case your internal keyboard is broken.

Answer (score 1):

First determine what is going on: Hardware or software problem.

If the keys work fine in the BIOS or when you boot from a Linux LiveCD or USB it is certainly a software issue. (The fact that both the external and the internal keyboard are affected is a strong, but not a 100%, indicator of this too.)
First check that the keyboard layout (in Regional Settings) is set correctly in Windows. If it is set to Dvorak, or something like that, some keys may not work at all or do something completely different than what they should be doing.
If wrong layout is not the problem delete the keyboard in the device manager. Then reboot. The keyboard should be re-detected with a fresh driver after the reboot and hopefully work again.
If that doesn't help either go back to a previous restore point or, if needed, re-install Windows.

If the keys do NOT work in Bios it has to be hardware (and yes: a broken internal keyboard can also interfere with the external keyboard under some conditions).
If the laptop is still under warranty call HP. Else get a replacement keyboard online and install it yourself. In most cases instruction videos can be found on Youtube.
HP has them (for most models) on their own web-site in the DIY support section.

Comment: Thank you for response , in  BIOS the same problem , but occasionally it works , is it maby  some conflict in  drivers ?

Comment: No drivers are loaded in a BIOS. There is only build-in code. If that worked before it should work now.

Comment: @Hennes Actually a UEFI Bios can, in theory, have drivers... But I have yet to actually encounter a UEFI bios that let me install them. And it would be even more unusual for a keyboard as that functionality is always required and thus has to be build-in.

Comment: You are correct. EFI firmware can have drivers. BIOS firmware does not. (sorry, puritan here. an UEFI BIOS does not exits. It is either BIOS or [u]EFI or something else like coreboot.)

Comment: @hennes You're right :-) If you want to be really pedantic: Coreboot I think qualifies as a BIOS replacement, which is technically speaking still "a BIOS".